# Как получить самую частую гласную букву в строке

Tags: java, сопоставление-с-образцом

Написал такой код, но с его помощью я получаю число повторений буквы в строке, как получить саму букву? никак не могу сообразить

```
public String getMostCommonVowelFromString(String[] array) {        //найти самую частую гласную букву в строке
    String result;
    int a = 0;
    int e = 0;
    int i = 0;
    int o = 0;
    int u = 0;

    String s;
    for (int j = 0; j < array.length; j++) {
        s = array[j];
        Matcher m = Pattern.compile("([AaEeIiOoUu])").matcher(s);
        while (m.find()) {
            if (m.group().matches("[aA]")) {
                a++;
            } else if (m.group().matches("[eE]")) {
                e++;
            } else if (m.group().matches("[iI]")) {
                i++;
            } else if (m.group().matches("[oO]")) {
                o++;
            } else if (m.group().matches("[uU]")) {
                u++;
            }
        }
    }
    System.out.println("A - " + a);
    System.out.println("E - " + e);
    System.out.println("I - " + i);
    System.out.println("O - " + o);
    System.out.println("U - " + u);

    int[] sortedArray = new int[5];
    sortedArray[0] = a;
    sortedArray[1] = e;
    sortedArray[2] = i;
    sortedArray[3] = o;
    sortedArray[4] = u;

    Arrays.sort(sortedArray);
    result = String.valueOf(sortedArray[4]); //возвращает число а надо букву соответствующую этому числу

    return result;  //как вернуть имя переменной а не значение?
}
```

Comment: используйте Map<String, Integer>, где храните букву и ее частоту повторения

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Задача достаточно тривиальна, но при этом Ваш код абсолютно нечитаемый. Представьте себе, что будет, когда сложность задачи возрастет в сотню раз...
Посему предлагаю Вам сделать так:

```
private final static Set<Character> VOWEL_CHARS = Stream.of('A','a','E','e','I','i','O','o','U','u').collect(Collectors.toSet());

public Map <String, Long> getMostCommonVowelFromString(String[] array) {
    return Arrays.stream(array)
            .map(s -> s.chars().mapToObj(c -> (char)c).toArray(Character[]::new))
            .flatMap(a -> Arrays.stream(a))
            .filter(c->VOWEL_CHARS.contains(c))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(ch -> String.valueOf(ch).toUpperCase(), Collectors.counting()));
}
```

Этот метод вернет вам коллекцию типа Map , где ключ - это буква, а значение - количество ее повторений.

Comment: спасибо! это помогло

Comment: Не за что) Учите джаву)

Answer (score 1):

```
Set<Character> vowels = "aeiou".chars()
                               .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                               .collect(Collectors.toSet());

String str = "Java 8 RulezZz";

Character mostFrequent = str.toLowerCase()
                            .chars()
                            .mapToObj(c -> (char) c)
                            .filter(vowels::contains)
                            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
                              Function.identity(),
                              Collectors.counting()))
                            .entrySet()
                            .stream()
                            .max(Map.Entry.comparingByValue())
                            .map(Map.Entry::getKey)
                            .get();
```

Answer (score 0):

При сортировке соответствие символа и переменной теряется. Но сортировка и не нужна - достаточно найти максимальное значение из переменных a,e,i,o,u с помощью операторов сравнения и if

Кроме того, использование регулярных выражений для такой задачи несколько расточительно.